# Sync local pouchdb databases between HTML pages

Tags: javascript, database, html, cordova, pouchdb

I have 2 different HTML pages in a phonegap app that have a PouchDB database to store data. Is it possible to sync the data between the two of them?

The docs on the site only talk about syncing to remote databases, but I am wondering if something like `PouchDB.sync('db', 'index.html/db2');` would work?

If not, is there anyway to sync data between the two?